# How to dynamic add Google analytics track code using php?

Tags: php, google-analytics

I would like to add track code for each link of in my email content
So , i have register a google analytic accounts and found that there is only 1 track code

therefore, how to use php , given a google analytics id and password given,

1. register for a new track code
2. add each code to a link (need to use php to add a 1px * 1 px image for each link?)
3. Return the codes added

Thank you

Besides, if i have to track the result  in Google analytic (traffic source ->campaign) or i can use an api that can integrate the result panel in Google analytic to my system ?

Thank you again for any kindly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question...

Are you trying to script a php program to automatically register analytics accounts? I think that's againt their policy.

If you want to dynamically include your trackign code to all pages then just create Analytics.js with the tracking code inside.

Then you use: `include("Include/Analytics.js");`
or `include("Include/Footer.php");` if you place the tracking code in a footer file..

Do this on every page you want the tracking code to appear.